# Exception Value: request' in Django

Tags: python, django, exception, request, django-pagination

I have the django code running with `1.3.1` version, and recently i updated it to django `1.6.1` and cleared most of the errors like `direct_to_template` functions and some `settings` etc., and can be able to run the site.

But for some pages i am getting the below error when it encounters `{% autopaginate object_list 20 %}` tag in templates

I am using `django-pagination(1.0.7)` for my pagination functionality

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/reports/safety/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'request'
Exception Location: /home/user/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py in __getitem__, line 56
Python Executable:  /home/user/.virtualenvs/proj/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.4
......
........


Error during template rendering

In template /home/user/users/apps/proj/templates/shared/report.html, error at line 41

request

40 <tbody>
41          {% autopaginate object_list 20 %}
42          {% for report in object_list %}
43               {{report}}
44               ........
               .........
          {% endfor %}
100 </tbody>
```

So can anyone please let me know why it is getting the above error and how to clear it ?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, Actually need to add `"django.core.context_processors.request",`setting in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting